# How can I check if the Launcher/Home screen is currently displayed

Tags: android, android-widget

I am working on a widget that is fetching and displaying some data.
The refresh rate is custom.

What I would like to do, is only fetch data when the widget is displayed (when the launcher is on top).

Is there a way to check if the launcher is displayed?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832321/which-launcher-is-running

Answer (score 1):

There's almost certainly no way of doing this, unless of course the homescreen has some API for requesting this information. Your best bet is probably listening for screen turn ons/turnoffs.

But even so, just pick a conservative refresh rate and let your users modify it.