# Which launcher is running?

Tags: android, launcher

Usually there is one launcher on an Android device.
But sometimes users install a few while only one of them is active.

How can I check which launcher is currently active on my Android device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The home screen is started with the [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) `ACTION_MAIN` with category `CATEGORY_HOME` (from the javadoc for `Intent`). Use a [`ResolveInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) to this intent to know what application will start.

This will give you the default Home application:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
final ResolveInfo res = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0); 
if (res.activityInfo == null) {
    // should not happen. A home is always installed, isn't it?
} else if ("android".equals(res.activityInfo.packageName)) {
    // No default selected     
} else {
     // res.activityInfo.packageName and res.activityInfo.name gives you the default app
}
```

Now, if you want to know which one is running, it will take more time, because [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) is slow:

```
// instead of the best, query all activities that match:
final List<ResolveInfo> list = ((PackageManager)getPackageManager()).queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
// TODO from there, use ActivityManager to know which one is running and is in the list
```

Comment: Need to mention that if there is no default launcher and more than one installed, then you'll get something like `com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity`.

Answer (score 5):

```
private String findLauncherPackageName(){       
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
    final ResolveInfo res = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0); 
    Log.e("ANDRO_ASYNC", String.format("findLauncherPackageName()%s",res.activityInfo.packageName));
    return res.activityInfo.packageName;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't always return the active launcher, it will return the default launcher, if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

**To improve upon previous answers, here is a self contained helper class you can use:**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;

public class LauncherFinder {

    /**
     * Checks to see if the App currently set as the system launcher
     * matches the given package name.
     *
     * @param context
     * @param packageName
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean isPackageSetAsLauncher(Context context, String packageName) {
        String launcherPackageName = getLauncherPackageName(context);
        return packageName.equals(launcherPackageName);
    }

    /**
     * Get the package name of the app currently set as the system launcher
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    public static String getLauncherPackageName(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

        ResolveInfo result = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0);

        if (result != null && result.activityInfo != null) {
            return result.activityInfo.packageName;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**and then use it like so:**

```
boolean isLauncher = LauncherFinder.isPackageSetAsLauncher(getApplicationContext(), "com.package.name");
```

This will return **true** if **com.package.name** is currently set as the default launcher.

Comment: to improve on this answer add this method to check if own app is launcher:

    public static boolean isMyAppLauncherDefault(Context context) {
        final String myPackageName = context.getPackageName();

        if (myPackageName.equals(getLauncherPackageName(context))) {
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can check the title of active launcher only if it is marked default. otherwwise you will get result like

```
com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity
```