# How to get the names of the launchers available on android?

Tags: android

So I want that when an activity is started ex:myactivity, it should get the names of all the applications that are launcher activities(ex:apex, nova,etc.) and list them. Is there any way to do that?
I wan that my app should search for this and show a list of apps that can be set as default home launchers just like default app manager does.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

[Default App Manager](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager&hl=en&ei=kp7VUdCtA4_qrQeLoYDACQ&usg=AFQjCNHor_f6tAR8c4_DZs5fEVNmtr1Zow&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bmk)
[Nova Launcher](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEAQFjAC&url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&ei=kp7VUYjDBMKPrQfF24HQDA&usg=AFQjCNH2DL_FP2s0PRjAgMZO_CinDwsCBA&bvm=bv.48705608,d.bmk)

Now how do I make it so that when a button is clicked the setting activity for the current default launcher is opened? We can do that in Default App Manager so I know its possible but I am unable to get to it.

Comment: What is a "launcher activity"?

Comment: apps which are defined as launchers like nova. There is an app called default app manager that lists the activities which are defined as launcher.

Comment: What is "nova"? What is "default app manager"?

Comment: Nova is an application that replaces your homescreen(i.e. your default launcher) 
And default app manager is an app with which you can set defaults to various things like default music player, default home screen, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve a List of installed applications (that have HOME as category) by doing this:

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Yes I have updated my post: mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); is what you are looking for.

Comment: But im not sure if your app can set / have permission to set the default home launcher ...

Comment: I have already done that. 
So I define pkgAppsList as a listview and show the result, right?

Comment: I don't know what you wanna do :) or what your app should look like, but yes, put the pkgAppsList in an BaseAdapter and display it in a ListView

Comment: Now how do I make it so that when a button is clicked the setting activity for the current default launcher is opened? We can do that in Default App Manager so I know its possible but I am unable to get to it.

Comment: So your question is, which activity do you must start to bring the launchers settings activity on screen? You must do that the way, like you will do with any other activity: Use an Intent. In the intent you need to specify the package name and Activity name of the Settings Activity of the selected launcher. But there is no standard  Intent you can send to make it work with every launcher. So you may need to check for every launchers setting activity ...

Comment: Oh yes thanks I might do that but for that would I have to extract to take a look at the package names of all launcher activities?

Comment: Okay actually there is a clever work around for this.
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167583/clearing-and-setting-the-default-home-application-solved[/link]