# about Launcher android

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher, android-launcher

I have 2 questions about launcher below:

1. I have 3-4 launchers on device, how can i know  which  launcher has been set default on my device (with code).(Done)
2. I have own custom launcher app, I want clear default launcher on my app and without use:

   ```
   Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS, packageURI);
   uninstallIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
   startActivity(uninstallIntent);
   ```

   as some app as: Kid's Shell or Kids Place. I have try  follow [Clearing and setting the default home application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167583/clearing-and-setting-the-default-home-application-solved) but nothing change.

Please show me how to solve 2 things. 
Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(defaultLauncherPackgeName);`

Added:

If you want to set your launcher as default, try:

```
     ComponentName cN = new ComponentName(mContext, FakeHome.class);
     p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,             PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

     Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
     mContext.startActivity(selector);

     p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
         android:name="com.test.FakeHome"
         android:enabled="false" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

Comment: Can i set default launcher for device without checking default on intent of device?

Comment: Some devices allow you to set default launcher without clear the default, but some do not. So you'd better clear the default setting first, then set the default launcher.

Comment: @lsaiah: I can't clear default launcher which not my launcher by your code. How to clear it? thanks

Comment: @dleviathan Your application can only clear its own package, and it is system behavior to set the default app.

Comment: @dleviathan If you want to set your app as default app, try:  ComponentName cN = new ComponentName(mContext, FakeHome.class);
         p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,             PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
 
         Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
         selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
         mContext.startActivity(selector);
 
         p.setComponentEnabledSetting(cN, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Comment: @dleviathan FaceHome in xml:   <activity
             android:name="com.test.FakeHome"
              android:enabled="false" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>  Just see my edit.

Comment: @lsaiah: Thanks! I have try this but I have problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697253/load-launcher-app-again/18698035?noredirect=1#18698035) with xml as
`<activity android:name=".LogInActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter></activity>
<activity android:name=".CheckDefLaunchActivity">
</activity>`

Comment: Have you try to remove `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`  You know other launchers(Default Android launcher, etc) do not contain this category

Comment: But i want my app run as both normal app and launcher (like some parental control). How i can do that?

Comment: Try to add a separate IntentFilter to the activity: `<activity android:name=".ActiviyName"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter></activity> `