# In a normal android app,how to get permission :android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS?

Tags: android

The permission android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS only used by system app,but in my project the requirement said that we need clear launcher defaults,so somebody help me. I search for google apis ,the result is 'this permission is not surppot after android version 2.2' .

Comment: There is a trick that will ask the user to set it, here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13239706/878126