# How do I get the Default app chooser dialog to appear even if the default app is already chosen already?

Tags: android

Suppose I have a browser app,

And I'd like a Settings to be called "Make default browser" to show the dialog chooser, even though the current default browser is not my app.

How can I make I show the app chooser dialog programmatically?

Thank you.

**Update** Following the lead from Michal's answer, I wrote this:

```
String url = FinalVariables.JAVELIN_URL;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.choose_javelin)));
```

While it does show the chooser dialog, it does not show the "Always", "Just once" option. How can I have that option to show?

Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html; http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CHOOSER

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a dirty nifty hack that allows you to do that.
The inspiration for this hack could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13239706/1900071)

#### The idea

is to make android think that a new browser has just been installed, feeding it a fake component with a typical browser intent-filter.
I shall provide a little test case as a proof-of-concept, and it is up to you to decide how you could use it in your real-world application.

#### The proposed approach

seems to be general and applicable in plenty of cases (not only for launchers and browsers) and depends only on intent filter  that is being fed to a resolver.

Lets assume that we want to override a default Activity for browsing simple **http://** link
We shall declare a fake browser activity alongside the real ones in *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<activity
    android:name=".FakeActivity"
    android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

FakeActivity is absolutely blank:

```
public class FakeActivity extends Activity {}
```

We'll show app chooser by pressing a simple button found in *activity_main.xml* and test the default behaviour by pressing another button:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View changeDefaultButton = findViewById(R.id.changeDefButton);
    changeDefaultButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showChooser();
        }
    });

    View testDefaultButton = findViewById(R.id.testDefaultButton);
    testDefaultButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            runDefaultApp();
        }
    });
}


void showChooser(){

    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName cm = new ComponentName(this, FakeActivity.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(cm, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    runDefaultApp();

    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(cm, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

}

void runDefaultApp(){
    Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    selector.setData(Uri.parse("http://stackoverflow.com"));
    startActivity(selector);
}
```

Every time you click on `changeDefaultButton`, the chooser dialog is shown (assuming there are at least two suitable browser apps installed). Also, **the chooser dialog always allows user to set the chosen application as default**.

#### Links:

[GitHub proof-of-concept project](https://github.com/ousenko/ForceNewDefaultAppChooserPoC)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create Intent with `ACTION_CHOOSER` which is obtained with `Intent.createChooser()` In method params pass initial intent and title. You can add more intent to this chooser by putting extra `Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` with array of intents.

Comment: this does not show the "Always", "Just once" option.