# List of default apps showing wrong in Android L

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop, android-package-managers

I want to get all default apps in Android L. I used bellow code but they give me a wrong solution. Let see my code first

```
private void getMyAppLauncherDefault() {
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    List<IntentFilter> filters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>();
    filters.add(filter);
    List<ComponentName> activities = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
    final PackageManager packageManager = (PackageManager) getPackageManager();

    packageManager.getPreferredActivities(filters, activities, null);
    for (ComponentName activity : activities) {

        Log.d(TAG,"======packet default:==="+activity.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

And this is log. The log shows a wrong result between `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox` and `com.vlingo.midas`. They are both Voice apps, but I set up `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox` as default. I do not know why the log shows `com.vlingo.midas`. How can I fix it? Thanks

```
 16:02:44.817 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.sec.android.gallery3d
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.android.mms
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.android.mms
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.vlingo.midas
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.sec.android.app.sbrowser
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.sec.android.gallery3d
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.android.mms
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.sec.android.app.launcher
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.sec.android.app.sbrowser
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.android.mms
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.sec.android.app.sbrowser
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.sec.android.gallery3d
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.android.mms
 16:02:44.827 /com.exam D/Sample: ======packet default:===com.google.android.apps.plus
```

update: There are default app names
[image]

Comment: It is likely that `com.vlingo.midas` supports an additional filter, for which it shows up. Print the respective filter with the package name to check for this.

Comment: @F43nd1r: How can we print it? The `filter` size just 1, while `filters` size is 4. But I cannot print the name of filters

Comment: may be com.vlingo.midas is default for different purpose/application.

Answer (score 2):

To check if your App is set as "Default" then please try this code:

```
 public static boolean isMyAppDefault(Context context) {
        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

        List<IntentFilter> filters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>();
        filters.add(filter);

        final String myPackageName = context.getPackageName();
        List<ComponentName> activities = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
        final PackageManager packageManager = (PackageManager) context.getPackageManager();

        packageManager.getPreferredActivities(filters, activities, null);

        for (ComponentName activity : activities) {
            if (myPackageName.equals(activity.getPackageName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: @user8430 if you get any problem let me know.

Comment: I think you and me get same source from someone. In your solution, it is similar my code above, just modify something. Please check your solution before posting.

Answer (score 2):

The code you added above is perfectly right. It does perform what it is meant to.

Now you have set `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox` voice app as default and that's why it's showing up in the log.
While `com.vlingo.midas` is showing probably because it's set as default for some other kind of category instead of voice.

Comment: How can you prove it? I do not think so. I check all

Comment: @user8430 I will need to try it out to prove it. I'll try it out and let you know

Comment: Do you find the solution. I am still looking forward to your testing

Comment: @user8430 I haven't tested yet. I'll surely try it as soon as possible.