# Make app as default messaging when sms received

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

Is it possible set app as default programmatically when broadcastreceiver get sms and unset after We no longer needed؟
Actually i Wanna delete sms in android 4.4+ that make app as defualt is only choice to delete sms in android 4.4+
thank you

Comment: check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991656/how-to-set-default-app-launcher-programmatically

Comment: thanks . is it possible all this operations do with code without interaction with user?