# Launcher chooser in intent is not working

Tags: android, launcher, android-launcher

I am able to trigger the launcher chooser popup with below code from where i can select my launcher. But in huawei tablet this code is not working

```
Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
selector.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(selector);
```

Please help me!!

Comment: Please check out my updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

This is actually possible with a little workaround:

Create an empty `Activity` that acts as a launcher called `FakeLauncherActivity`. Add it to your manifest as a **disabled** component:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.path.to.your.FakeLauncherActivity"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Check whether your desired launcher activity is the default one..

If not, offer the user to choose the preferred launcher activity like this:

```
public static void resetPreferredLauncherAndOpenChooser(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, com.path.to.your.FakeLauncherActivity.class);
    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Intent selector = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    selector.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    selector.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(selector);

    packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

This method temporarily enables `FakeLauncherActivity`, which leads to a change in the set of available launcher activities, which forces Android to forget its default launcher. You will see something like...

```
521-735/system_process I/PackageManager﹕ Result set changed, dropping preferred activity for Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 } type null
```

... in your log.

The method then simply opens a launcher intent where you can see all installed launchers and the buttons "Always" / "Just once".
Finally, the method disables `FakeLauncherActivity` again so that it doesn't display in the list.

You could repeat that as often as you want and only let the user proceed if your desired launcher activity is set as default.

Source: [Got It From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991656/how-to-set-default-app-launcher-programmatically)

Comment: Hi Umang,Thanks for replay . Above code is not working. It will just show the chooser popup . But I need native Launcher chooser popup with "always" and "Just once" option to make my launcher as default. :(