# How to implement FakeLauncher for Setting Launcher Programatically on Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, launcher

I'm creating an Android Launcher in Flutter. Whenever the user opens the App I need to show the Launcher selection screen. I have found the answer here, but it is for native Android development. How do I integrate this with Flutter ?

[How to set default app launcher programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991656/how-to-set-default-app-launcher-programmatically)

I have tried creating the new activity but I'm not sure where to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

To set a page at the initial route of the `flutter`. You can use [initialRoute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/initialRoute.html) in your `MaterialApp` of your `main.dart` file. Then specify your page in your `routes`. Read about [Defining the routes](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes#2-define-the-routes)

```
MaterialApp(
  // Start the app with the "/" named route. In this case, the app starts
  // on the FirstScreen widget.
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // When navigating to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen widget.
    '/': (context) => FakeLauncher()
  },
);
```