# How to call the system menu as in the Chrome browser to set the default browser

Tags: java, android, kotlin, browser, webview

I have a Browser app, I need to set it as my default browser. I want to call such a system menu (as in the photo) only instead of Chrome - the name of my application. How to do it?[enter image description here

[I want to call such a system menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zctea.jpg)

Comment: you can check this question   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991656/how-to-set-default-app-launcher-programmatically.

Comment: @Shree thanks it works.
Helped RoleManager.
How can I mark your answer as correct?