# Is it possible to write a .NET MAUI application for Android using Intent.CategoryHome?

Tags: java, c#, android, maui, android-launcher

I am writing an application for Android 7.1 using .NET MAUI (.NET 6.0) that behaves something like "Nova Launcher" and similar apps. I am stuck on figuring out how to make the app "override" the default Android launcher (when the home button is pressed my app will show instead of the Android launcher app).

The first thing I tried was searching on Google how to set my Android app to behave like a launcher and [I found this old blog post](https://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/how-to-write-custom-launcher-app-in-android/) which I think is correct because I have seen "android.intent.category.HOME" multiple times already while searching up why my code didn't work and other questions on Stack Overflow (Not limiting myself on .NET MAUI but searching for Java questions aswell), but the AndroidManifest.xml file doesn't work with .NET MAUI because the way the main activity works. Instead of it appearing on the AndroidManifest.xml (Platforms/Android) it is represented on MainActivity.cs (also Platforms/Android). I have tried to override the OnCreate() method and adding

```
public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    PackageManager.SetComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(this, Class), ComponentEnabledState.Enabled, ComponentEnableOption.DontKillApp); // with and without this line
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMain);
    intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryHome);
    intent.AddCategory(Intent.CategoryDefault);
    StartActivity(intent);
}
```

to it but it simply didn't work. Nothing important on device log (I am using an emulator).
The last thing I tried before giving up and asking ChatGPT was searching for Java questions and trying to translate the code to C#, but nothing worked. The only thing slightly different I tried was
adding a "FakeLauncherActivity" activity that is disabled at default to the AndroidManifest.xml and then reactivating it using [this answer's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30617251/13891872) (that I translated to C#). ChatGPT only caused my app to crash and do nothing

Comment: You translated it wrong AFAIK (but never done app with maui) you should do this via attributes on Activity... Then they are translated to manifest file

Comment: There is a topic in official documentation called "Android app manifest" feel free to read it

Comment: @Selvin Thank you for mentioning it, I have progressed a little bit. It now brings up the "Select a Home app" dialog, allowing me to select between the default launcher and my app. The problem now is that when I set my app as the default launcher, it throws a NullReferenceException. The following URL is a picture of the Call Stack and exception window: https://i.ibb.co/MMR0dTy/image-2023-09-03-225941968.png.

Comment: [Activity(MainLauncher = false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] {Intent.ActionMain}, Categories = new[] {Intent.CategoryLauncher, Intent.CategoryHome, Intent.CategoryDefault})] This is my MainActivity.cs @Selvin

Comment: Would you mind adding everything you've tried and the issues you are facing into the question, may be i can help you with this

Comment: @FreakyAli It was no use, the proper way to do it is how I am doing it but I have now moved to making it on different activities, thanks trying though