# I need to programmatically open the home screen launcher in my Oppo phone

Tags: android

I need to open screen

> Setting > App Management > Default App Management > Home Screen

in Android programatically. I have tried

```
Intent i = new Intent (Settings.ACTION_HOME_SETTINGS) and ACTION_SETTINGS
```

but it takes me to the screen before Home Screen.

Comment: Format your post correctly please !

Answer (score 0):

Misunderstood what you wanted sorry !

You can find an answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39487021/3780625

Hope it helps !

Comment: For the benefit of future visitors to this site, could you please explain what your code does?

Comment: Edited my answer