# how to not let android OS to set my app link, in other default in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing react native where I have used the WalletConnect third party library which prompting the various supported app while connecting with other app.

When I connect my app with other app first time it show all app but when user select `set as default` then user can't be able to see all three options next time.

Please check screen shot :-
[image]

However we can clear the default settings from settings. But is there any way to restrict android OS to not let set my app link in other app's default.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());
```

Comment: Where it has to use ?  in MainApplication ?

Comment: Yes use in MainApplication or in Launcher Activity.

Comment: no, its not working

Comment: Check with this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13239706/10970789