# Android custom launcher that launches the default Launcher

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher, android-launcher, kiosk-mode

As my first Android app, I'm programming a kiosk for a working use. This app is set as default launcher and full-screen, so, when the tablet boot, the kiosk is already started and the user can't open other apps or escape from the kiosk app.

The last thing I'm not able to code is the ability to change from my kiosk/launcher to the default Android Launcher. I've prepared a password input: if the password is right, I would like to launch the Launcher.

This is what I have so far:

```
if (message.equals("password")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Scegli:"));
}
```

I've tried this app only in the Android Studio's emulator, where the default launcher is the Android Launcher: with these instructions, the app simply goes on the default Android Launcher. So I suppose that, on the tablet, despite the createChooser, I only reach the default launcher, that will be my kiosk.

Comment: See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594192/remove-activity-as-default-launcher?rq=1 The idea is to make android forget that you are the default launcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your Intent like this:

```
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Comment: please read the documentation for CATEGORY_LAUNCHER and CATEGORG_HOME.

Answer (score 1):

*This is the OP's solution, migrated here from the question body*

```
if (message.equals("password")) {
    getPackageManager().clearPackagePreferredActivities(getPackageName());
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```