# How to tell if a device is using TouchWiz programmatically

Tags: android, android-widget, samsung-touchwiz

I need to check from within my code whether the device I am using has TouchWiz enabled. I tried using

**if(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER.equals(MANUFACTURER_SAMSUNG))**

But it turns out some devices are made by Samsung and don't use TouchWiz.

How can I figure this out?

Comment: probably just the one with a custom rom,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check the default launcher.. i believe touchwiz is a launcher

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); 
final ResolveInfo res = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0); 
if (res.activityInfo == null) {
    // should not happen. A home is always installed, isn't it?
} if ("android".equals(res.activityInfo.packageName)) {
    // No default selected     
} else {
     // res.activityInfo.packageName and res.activityInfo.name gives you the default app
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked nicely. The package name for touchwiz is "com.sec.android.app.launcher", right?

Answer (score 0):

You can get list of preferred activities from PackageManager. Use getPreferredActivities() method.

```
boolean isUsingTochwiz() {

    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

    List<IntentFilter> filters = new ArrayList<IntentFilter>();
    filters.add(filter);

    final String myPackageName = "INSERT TOUCHWIZ PACKAGE NAME HERE";
    List<ComponentName> activities = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
    final PackageManager packageManager = (PackageManager) getPackageManager();

    packageManager.getPreferredActivities(filters, activities, null);

    for (ComponentName activity : activities) {
        if (myPackageName.equals(activity.getPackageName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Taken from: [How to check if my application is the default launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299427/how-to-check-if-my-application-is-the-default-launcher)