# How to make app as a default system launcher?

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-launcher

I have developed the launcher application, for the first time when I installed it on device android system pop up chooser dialogue with two options i.e. Always & Just once. I selected "Always" now my app becomes default launcher but issue is when I update the app, the system pop up the same chooser dialogue again, I don't want to show that pop up. How to make the app as a default system launcher? To achieve this, Do I need to create system level app?

I have used following permission to make the app a launcher

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />               
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that is possible (at least without root, in which case I can't help sorry!), in the worse case scenario you can configure it like you could ask user to select your app as default the first time it runs

Comment: @TomTsagk  yes It's done. but after updating it is asking again which I want to avoid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to change the user preferences. Google does not allow developer to change user preferences.

A workaround may be useful, you can check for if your application is default launcher through a service and then prompt user to choose your application as default.

You can find how to check if your application is the default launcher from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8361115) (tried this one, it works for me) or [here](http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/get-default-launcher-pogrammatically-android/)

Then you can prompt the user to select your application if it is not the default launcher. A workaround to do so is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13239706).

Comment: while it makes itself default launcher, but when i press home button it opens the app, but pressing back button takes to previous default launcher, which i don't want to happen.

Comment: @VikasPandey did you find any proper solution for "back press" issue? I have overridden the "onBackPressed" function with no "super.onBackPressed" call. Not sure if it's the best solution.