# How can I open android application at booting time?

Tags: android

I have a requirement of client. Client has to load android application on android tablet. He doesn't want other applications to be opened. He wants his app should be opened at booting time OR if you restart it.As I am an android developer. Application is ready now.How can I fulfill his requirement.He doesn't want user to interact with another application.He can't go home screen. Is it possible?

Can someone help me with correct steps so I can try on one device.

Thanks,

Prashant

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Kiosk mode of your tablet, this mode is different is you use Android or IOS. (for me Android is better because you can't quit instead of IOS... with the round button)

http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/

Comment: Thanks ZelkiN. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One Possible solution might be: make your app a default launcher. you can do this by adding this lines to your manifest :

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />               
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
</intent-filter>
```

after this you just need to select your app as a default launcher.

Some useful links about it:

[How to set default app launcher programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991656/how-to-set-default-app-launcher-programmatically)

[How to make app as default system launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422208/how-to-make-app-as-a-default-system-launcher)

Another solution is to get the android source code and compile it and build your own kernel with your favorite apps.
some useful links about how to build a kernel:

[Building the System](https://source.android.com/source/building.html)

[Establishing a Build Environment](https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)

[Compile android kernel source beginners guide](https://www.movzio.com/howto/compile-android-kernel-source-beginners-guide-2/)

Of course I know the second way is a little difficult. ;)

Comment: Thanks Milad.
Of course, second suggestion is quite difficult at this level. But yes, it is helpful.

Comment: @Prashanth Your wellcome ;)