# How to reset default app programmatically, which user previously chooses as open Always

Tags: android

How to reset default app programmatically, which user previously chooses as open Always?
Expected end result is to show the app chooser again,  when user view the file next time.

Thanks.

Comment: An app cannot remove other apps as the default handler of an intent, it can only remove itself as the default handler (see [`clearPackagePreferredActivities`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#clearPackagePreferredActivities(java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 9):

By default, Android does not allow that. Security reasons and so on.

However, there is a loophole - The default reset every time the system recognizes a new component was added which can handle the given intent.

So, you will need to do something like this:

```
public void resetDefault() {
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName component = new ComponentName("com.example.app", "com.mypackage.Component");
    manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

*com.mypackage.Component* is a dummy `Activity`, which you have in your manifest and which is not enabled by default. It needs to have an `IntentFilter` with the Intent you want to be default app of, like this:

```
<activity
    android:name="Component"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SOME_ACTION" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.SOME_CATEGORY" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The method will enable the dummy component and the system will be notified that a new possible receiver was added (the same happens when you install a new launcher for example) and will reset defaults. The the code will disable the dummy so it does not show in the chooser.

You will probably want to check if your app is default or not, and if there is a default app at all. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299427/how-to-check-if-my-application-is-the-default-launcher) for details on how to do that.

Comment: Brilliant idea dude!

Comment: Glad it helped :D